# Как выполнить запрос с UNION ALL из двух одинаковых таблиц с сортировкой

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Есть собственно запрос

```
SELECT * FROM `debit` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 15) 
UNION ALL (SELECT * FROM `credit` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 15
```

Запрос выполняю через PDO

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare(
"(SELECT * FROM `debit` ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 15) 
UNION ALL (SELECT * FROM `credit` ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 15)"
);
$sth->execute();
```

Вывожу в таблицу но почему то значения идут как будто бутербродом. То есть сначала отсортированные данные из таблицы `debit` далее по списку так же отсортированные `credit`, а мне необходимо перемешать их так как будто они из одной таблицы

Comment: Начнем с того что таблица должна быть одна

Comment: Как тогда можно сделать выборку с двух таблиц с одинаковой структурой?

Comment: общий `order by` то напишите по итогу

Comment: Не работает ```SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM `debit` ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 15) UNION ALL (SELECT * FROM `credit` ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 15) ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 15```

Comment: Ещё раз: таблица должна быть **одна**

Comment: @teran ну причина то очевидна, и она не в ордер бай

Comment: @Ипатьев мб гражданин там достал базу, влил дамп и делает по быстрому выборку. на кой ему в таком случаев сливать таблицу в одну?

Comment: `) union all (` замените еще на просто `union all`, что-то не заметил сразу

Comment: Мне принципиально необходимо 2 таблицы. Если мой вариант категорически не верный дайте может наводку как реализовать решение моей задачи. Буду признателен

Comment: 2 таблицы - это и есть категорически неверный вариант. Откуда вообще идея, что "принципиально две"?

Comment: @teran не помогло

Comment: а, вот сейчас с компа отредактировал и вижу что действительно, у него два отдельных запроса

Comment: ```(SELECT * FROM `debit` ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 15) UNION ALL (SELECT * FROM `credit` ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 15) ORDER BY `date` DESC /* LIMIT 15 */``` Только дурь всё это - перемешивать в кучу, да так. что формально не понять, из какой из двух таблиц взята запись... И да - под одну сущность (видимо, "движение средств") создавать две таблицы только на основании одного атрибута неразумно.

Comment: что-то у вас скобки прыгают при каждом редактировании запроса. юнион уберите во подзапрос, а ко внешнему добавьте сортировку.

Comment: @teran А зачем тут вообще внешний запрос? он тупо лишний.

Comment: @Akina у него по началу был

Comment: А что мешает сделать 1 таблицу с, к примеру, enum дебет-кредит?

Comment: @InDevX Так и сделал пока искал решение